# one SSIS task get executed after the previous one fail

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

I make a simple package which is similar to the one having issue.

Check the pic below:

[image]

here is the expression for the right precedence constraint:

[image]

But after executing the package, here is the result, could anybody tell me why? What I desired result is the `Script Task2` did not get executed when `Execute SQL Task` fail.

[image]

Comment: Script task 2 should be set with a Expression and Constraint.  Set Constraint = Success.

Comment: It works, what is the logic of Expression and Constraint?

Comment: i kind get the point, but if so, why we need `Expression` as one of the option since `Expression and Constraint` and `Expression or Constraint` cover the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a summary for the sake of record.

Script task 2 should be set with a Expression and Constraint. Set Constraint = Success

You also asked what's the point?
You have some flexibility with design in this way.  Often you can have a variable which will default to false, unless something happens successfully beforehand.  In that case you only need the expression setting.

Also, on this topic, I suggest avoid using the OR operator and stick with the default of AND.  Your packages will be easier to understand.  You can usually accomplish what you need with Success, failure and the occasional expression.

m